# How to force GNU make to print verbose but only upon error

Tags: cmake, compilation, linker, gnu-make

I have a build system which uses CMake to generate Makefiles. By default, `make` will not echo the commands (e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 ...`), but we can specify `VERBOSE=1` to do that.

I want a selective version, where it will not show the verbose commands, but if there is an error, then it will print the full compile / link command that caused the error.

Is there such a setting?

Comment: GNU Make shows each command in full by default (i.e. unless `@` is prefixed to
recipe commands that are not to be echoed). The variable `VERBOSE` has no
intrinsic meaning to `make`. It is used by other build-systems, notably CMake,
that generate make-files for GNU Make that will issue `@`-silenced recipe commands
unless `VERBOSE` has been defined. If your question actually concerns CMake or
another build system, please clarify it.

Comment: `VERBOSE=1` is not a "setting" of GNU make.  It's a setting created by the people who wrote your makefiles (I suspect CMake since that's what they use).  So unless the people who wrote your makefiles also provided the facility you're looking for the answer is no... you'll have to ask them to be sure.  FWIW, Makefiles created by CMake do not have such a feature (that I'm aware of).

Comment: Thanks: I was not aware of this, since I did not build the build system I'm using myself. I did remember that hand-rolled Makefiles would echo their commands in full however (error or no error).

Comment: Hand-rolled makefiles behave however the person who authored them wrote them to behave.  If the author wrote them so they always echoed their commands in full, then they'd do so.  If not, not.  it's true that by default in a simple recipe with no options to specify otherwise, make will echo the command it's about to run before it runs the command.  But there are ways to modify that behavior, both by the makefile author and the makefile user.

Comment: It would be great if CMake generated Makefiles that would do this. I asked a similar question recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553915/how-to-produce-a-make-build-that-is-verbose-only-on-failure?rq=1